# How can I dynamically disable a single required field from validation in a form?

Tags: forms

This is an extension of this question:

[Need help with AJAX callback function for text field validation in form_alter](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/154573/need-help-with-ajax-callback-function-for-text-field-validation-in-form-alter)

I have a form with a Username autocomplete field (txn_user). The editors want to be able to enter a UID (txn_userid) as an alternative way of specifying the User for the form. They want to be able to enter the UID and skip the Username field altogether.

So in my form validation function, I want to be able to disable the required property (and all other validation) of the Username field during a Submit IF the editor typed in a UID field. In other words: the UID field should 'short-circuit' the Username field.

This is what I have so far (which doesn't work, obviously). Or do I need to do this via AJAX or straight JS?

```
function _validate_add_userpoints_userid(&$form, &$form_state) {
    $values = $form_state['values'];
    if( $values['txn_userid'] ) {
        $newuser = user_load($values['txn_userid']);
        if( ! $newuser) {
          form_set_error('txn_userid', 'You have entered an invalid UID. Either leave this blank and select a Username or enter a valid UID');          
    }
    else {  
        // this part works... the User Name is properly assigned.
        $form['txn_user']['#value'] = $newuser->name;       
        $form_state['values']['txn_user'] = $newuser; 
        $form_state['input']['txn_user'] = $newuser->name;          

        // this part doesn't work... the User Name field is still required on submit.
        $form['txn_user']['#disabled'] = TRUE;
        $form['txn_user']['#ajax_processed'] = TRUE;
        $form['txn_user']['#required'] = FALSE;
        $form['txn_user']['#needs_validation'] = FALSE;         
        unset($form['txn_user']['#process']);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You must specify your validate function. See here: http://www.codeexpertz.com/blog/drupal/drupal-8-custom-form-validate-and-submit-hookformalter-example

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use conditional field module?

https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields

By this module you can disable the requirement of fields when something happens to another field. you can also implement your form as a content type so its node/add page will be your form. Then by using the different hooks you can add autocomplete field or do any thing else

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. I'd -rather- just have code to do this one small thing. The site is pretty well 'done' and I hate adding new modules for just one thing. For small things, I much prefer just having one bit of well-commented code in MY_MODULE. Seems easier for management.

Comment: This module is very tiny and it is more reasonable to reuse the codes that their safety and well performance are already tested and proved.